# Determining whether Z = min{X,Y} is geometrically distributed and finding the corresponding parameter.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, geometric-distribution

Let the numbers p and q in the interval (0, 1) be given.
Assume that X ∼ Geometric(p) and Y ∼ Geometric(q) are independent random variables.

Show that Z = min{X,Y} is geometrically distributed and find the corresponding parameter.

How do i approach this, because i can't really remember how i'm supposed to show/determine that Z = min{X,Y} is geometrically distributed. I also have no idea about how i should find the corresponding parameter and frankly i'm not sure i understand what the corresponding parameter actually is.

Well i think i know that
$$
\begin{align*} 
P( \min\{X,Y\}) &= P( \min\{X,Y\} > k) \\
&= P((X > k), (Y > k)) \\
&= P(X > k)P(Y > k) \\
&= P(X > k)^2
\end{align*}
$$
After that i'm assuming i have to use the probability mass function (PMF) or the cumulative distribution function (CDF) for a geometric distribution, but i don't know which to use or how im supposed to show that it is a geometric distribution like this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yeah i know, i will try to explain myself better, but it will take me some time.

Comment: I have tried to write down what i know explain myself better, but it took time to understand my thoughts and get an overview of what i know and don't know.

Comment: I removed the tag "distribution-theory" which is not about probability distributions but the generalized functions of Laurent Schwartz https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X\sim Geo(p)$ and $Y\sim Geo(q)$, then $\min\{X,Y\}\sim Geo(1-(1-p)(1-q))$. Think like that: You are looking at the first time of success from either $X$ or $Y$. The probability of both events not happening is $(1-p)(1-q)$. Therefore the probability of at least one success is $1-(1-p)(1-q)$.

Comment: You are then using the CDF right? I'm not sure how you get that the probability of both events not happening is $(1 - p)(1 - q)$. Is it through the CDF or am i completely lost?

Comment: The idea of geometric distribution is that we are looking at the first time some event happens. For example if $X$=the first time we throw 5 on a fair dice, then $X\sim Geo(1/6)$. In your case, the event from $X$ happens with probability $p$ and the event from $Y$ happens with probability $q$. Therefore the probability of $X$ not happening is $1-p$ and for $Y$ it's $1-q$. Because the two variables are independent, the probability of none of the two events happening are the probabilites of each one not happening multiplied.

Comment: Therefore if $\min\{X,Y\}=k$, that means that there was no success in first $k-1$ tries: $((1-p)(1-q))^{k-1}$. In the $k$-th try at least one event happened. The probability of that is $1-P(none happens)=1-(1-p)(1-q)$. Therefore: $P(\min\{X,Y\}=k)=((1-p)(1-q))^{k-1}(1-(1-p)(1-q))$. This is by definition the geometric distribution with parameter $1-(1-p)(1-q)$

Comment: Okay that makes sense now, but what do i do with this information? How does it help.

Comment: But that wouldn't make sense considering the desired result should be: $p+q-pq$.

Comment: $p+q-pq=1-(1-p)(1-q)$. If you need PMF, it's in my previous comment. The CDF is then simply $P(\min\{X,Y\}\leq k)=\sum_{n=1}^kP(\min\{X,Y\}=n)$.

Comment: Wait what, have i missed something here.

Comment: Oh, now i know: $p + q = 1$ while $pq = (1 - p)(1 - q)$

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: No problem. But be careful: $pq$ is not $(1-p)(1-q)$ and  $p+q$ is not 1. You will get the desired equality by simplifying $1-(1-p)(1-q)$